# Wordpress use add_rewrite_endpoint without traililng slash

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting

Is it possible to use add_rewrite_endpoint without the trailing slash? For instance, I have it working now to add "deals" to the end of the permalink like domain.com/category/post/deals. However, what this really needs to be in my case is domain.com/category/post-deals. Any thoughts?

```
function wpd_add_deals(){
    add_rewrite_endpoint( 'deals', EP_PERMALINK );
}
add_action( 'init', 'wpd_add_deals' );

add_filter('request', function($vars) {
    if (isset($vars['deals'])) {
        $vars['deals'] = true;
    }
    return $vars;
});

add_filter('template_include', function($template) {
    if (is_singular() && get_query_var('deals')) {
        $post = get_queried_object();
        return locate_template(['single-actor-movies.php']);
    }
    return $template;
});
```